# Call to undefined method in facebook call to publishUserAction

Tags: php, facebook

I'm getting the following using the PHP client on my server (connecting via FBML). I've included the appropriate php files (facebook etc..)

```
Fatal error: 
     Call to undefined method FacebookRestClient::feed_publishUserAction() 
      in ..../index.php on line 50
```

I'm trying to use the [example given](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Feed.publishUserAction#Example_Requests).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a quick browse/grep through your Facebook API files (facebookapi_php5_restlib.php) and make sure that the `feed_publishUserAction()` method exists.  Perhaps you're using an older version of the API library?

Comment: This was the right idea, too bad I wasn't able to figure it out - looks like all their effort is going into connect.

Comment: even the most updated version of the facebook API lacks this critical function! wtf

Comment: this shouldn't be the accepted answer since a normal "facebookapi_php5_restlib.php" that you downloaded from facebook doesn't contain the feed_publishUserAction function

Answer (score 0):

OMG I found the answer

Because the facebookapi_php5_restlib.php that facebook.com provided you is a piece of outdated shit

i.e. you won't be able to find the word feed_publishUserAction in the facebookapi_php5_restlib.php file

HOWEVER, the [official facebook smiley demo](http://svn.facebook.com/svnroot/platform/samples/packages/smiley.tar.gz) from [this facebook wiki page](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Demos) , contained a more completed facebookapi_php5_restlib.php , along with the feed_publishUserAction function

Which finger would you like to show to the facebook developer staffs?